# How to use MVVM ViewModel to change stuff in a View based on a ListView SelectionChanged event

Tags: c#, mvvm, uwp, viewmodel, xbind

I want to make a UWP application with a ListBox navigation whose selected item determines the content of a frame. When the selection changes, the frame content should change. I found an example for how to this (Method 1 below), but it uses event handlers in the code behind. I want to learn MVVM with this project and thus want to use a MVVM solution to this problem. I'm new to MVVM and my current understanding is that in order to decouple the View from the ViewModel, ViewModels shouldn't reference anything particular to the View. Is this a correct understanding? The only way I can think of using the ViewModel to change the frame view is to basically move the event handler code to the ViewModel and pass in the Frame to the constructor (Method 2 below). But that violates my understanding of the ViewModel relationship to the View since the ViewModel is referencing particular instances of things in the View; furthermore it seems like pointless overhead and like it would give very little organization benefit.

How would you implement a MVVM solution to this problem? Or is this a case where using event handlers is better?

**METHOD 1 - Event handler:**
This code is based on an example Microsoft provides. (Here's the link to the relevant code: https://github.com/microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/Playlists/cs)

```cs
public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
{
    List<Scenario> scenarios = new List<Scenario>
    {
        new Scenario() { Title = "Scenario 1", ClassType = typeof(Scenario1) },
        new Scenario() { Title = "Scenario 2", ClassType = typeof(Scenario2) }
    };

    public MainPage()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
    }

    protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
    {
        ScenarioControl.ItemsSource = scenarios;
    }

    private void ScenarioControl_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        ListBox scenarioListBox = sender as ListBox;
        Scenario s = scenarioListBox.SelectedItem as Scenario;
        if (s != null)
        {
            ScenarioFrame.Navigate(s.ClassType);
        }
    }
}

public class Scenario
{
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public Type ClassType { get; set; }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return Title;
    }
}
```

```xml
<!-- MainPage.xaml -->
<Grid>
    <SplitView x:Name="Splitter" IsPaneOpen="True" DisplayMode="Inline">
        <SplitView.Pane>
            <RelativePanel>
                <ListBox x:Name="ScenarioControl" SelectionChanged="ScenarioControl_SelectionChanged"/>
            </RelativePanel>
        </SplitView.Pane>
        <RelativePanel>
            <Frame x:Name="ScenarioFrame" />
        </RelativePanel>
    </SplitView>
</Grid>
```

**METHOD 2 - MVVM(?):**

```xml
<!-- MainPage.xaml -->
<Grid>
    ...
    <ListBox x:Name="ScenarioControl" SelectionChanged="{x:Bind MyViewModel.SwitchScenario}"/>
    ...
</Grid>
```

```cs
// MainPage.xaml.cs
...
    public MainPage()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
        MyViewModel = new MyViewModel(ScenarioFrame);
    }
...
    MyViewModel MyViewModel { get; set; }
}
```

```cs
// MyViewModel.cs
public class MyViewModel
{
    public MyViewModel(Frame scenarioFrame)
    {
        ScenarioFrame = scenarioFrame;
    }

    public void SwitchScenario(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        ListBox scenarioListBox = sender as ListBox;
        Scenario s = scenarioListBox.SelectedItem as Scenario;
        if (s != null)
        {
            ScenarioFrame.Navigate(s.ClassType);
        }
    }

    public Frame ScenarioFrame { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You’ll need PropertyChangedNotification when your model property changes- anything binding to the model property will then update automatically.

Also Bindings.Update() is your friend sometimes.

And if you’re going to have a View and a ViewModel you’ll need to set the DataContext of your View to the instance of the ViewModel or Model you are binding to.

Comment: I don't think this answers the question. True, this example doesn't demonstrate the model, but that's because I think it's irrelevant to my question. I believe that using x:bind and referencing the View's instance of the ViewModel makes setting the DataContext unnecessary. Is there a way I can clarify my question?

Answer (score 0):

> How would you implement a MVVM solution to this problem? Or is this a case where using event handlers is better?

For implementing MVVM navigation, you could refer [Template 10](https://github.com/Windows-XAML/Template10) and [Template Studio](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=WASTeamAccount.WindowsTemplateStudio) workflow.

In template 10, it bind `Click` event with navigation method.

```
<controls:PageHeader x:Name="pageHeader" RelativePanel.AlignLeftWithPanel="True"
                     RelativePanel.AlignRightWithPanel="True"
                     RelativePanel.AlignTopWithPanel="True" Text="Main Page">

    <!--  secondary commands  -->
    <controls:PageHeader.SecondaryCommands>
        <AppBarButton Click="{x:Bind ViewModel.GotoSettings}" Label="Settings" />
        <AppBarButton Click="{x:Bind ViewModel.GotoPrivacy}" Label="Privacy" />
        <AppBarButton Click="{x:Bind ViewModel.GotoAbout}" Label="About" />
    </controls:PageHeader.SecondaryCommands>

</controls:PageHeader>
```

**ViewModel**

```
 public void GotoDetailsPage() =>
     NavigationService.Navigate(typeof(Views.DetailPage), Value);

 public void GotoSettings() =>
     NavigationService.Navigate(typeof(Views.SettingsPage), 0);
```

In Template Studio, it navigates with `NavHelper` class.

```
<winui:NavigationViewItem x:Uid="Shell_Main" Icon="Document" helpers:NavHelper.NavigateTo="views:MainPage" />
<winui:NavigationViewItem x:Uid="Shell_Blank" Icon="Document" helpers:NavHelper.NavigateTo="views:BlankPage" />
<winui:NavigationViewItem x:Uid="Shell_MediaPlayer" Icon="Document" helpers:NavHelper.NavigateTo="views:MediaPlayerPage" />
<winui:NavigationViewItem x:Uid="Shell_WebView" Icon="Document" helpers:NavHelper.NavigateTo="views:WebViewPage" />


<ic:EventTriggerBehavior EventName="ItemInvoked">
                <ic:InvokeCommandAction Command="{x:Bind ViewModel.ItemInvokedCommand}" />
            </ic:EventTriggerBehavior>
```

**ViewModel**

```
private void OnItemInvoked(WinUI.NavigationViewItemInvokedEventArgs args)
{
    if (args.IsSettingsInvoked)
    {
        NavigationService.Navigate(typeof(SettingsPage));
        return;
    }

    var item = _navigationView.MenuItems
                    .OfType<WinUI.NavigationViewItem>()
                    .First(menuItem => (string)menuItem.Content == (string)args.InvokedItem);
    var pageType = item.GetValue(NavHelper.NavigateToProperty) as Type;
    NavigationService.Navigate(pageType);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reference to Template 10. I think that route shows promise for me. Do you know of a control it may have to update the page that shows within a <frame>? Like, is there a way to make `Navigate()` navigate only within a frame, not away from MainPage?

Comment: Do you mean that you just want to use `this.Frame.Navigate(type page)`?

Comment: No, that is the "MVVM" solution I came up with above in "Method 2". But the only way for that to work is if the ViewModel knows about the View's frame. As stated above in my original post, `my current understanding is that in order to decouple the View from the ViewModel, ViewModels shouldn't reference anything particular to the View. Is this a correct understanding?` If I were to use a Frame.Navigate() call for an event on a different control box (such as ListBox or controls:PageHeader), I don't know how to do that w/o the ViewModel know about things in the View. Does that make sense?

Comment: Yep, it is correct that *ViewModels shouldn't reference anything particular to the View*. And you could use `NavigationService` to host all the navigation in your view model just like Template 10.